# Sequence of deletion from a Binary Search Tree

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, b-tree

as we know,Topology of a BST has impressed upon the sequence of Insertion to that , but I have a question: what about sequence of deletion?
Does it have influence on Topology of Tree. In other words, 
assume that we have a BST of this numbers : {1,2,3,4,...,10}
if I want to delete nodes 2 & 4 , is it difference between , first delete 2 and then delete 4 or vice versa .

Comment: This is relatively simple to check on your own. There are a bunch of online simulators that simulate the behavior of BST. But to answer your question. Think about how the tree is built. If it is completely balanced and you delete two nodes in different parts of the tree, then the normal deletion algorithm will take over (get max of the left subtree from the removed node and replace it with that node) and the topology will change. So to truly answer your question, yes the sequence of deletes can change how the tree turns out.

Comment: thanks ,I found an example that show this truth

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your studying!